# for @RequestMapping No mapping found for HTTP request with URI in spring mvc. I am using java configuration

Tags: spring-mvc

Main controller is home and I want redirect to "http://localhost:8081/Spring_Practise/homev"

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home")
public class HomeController 
{
   @RequestMapping(value="/homev" , method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView homes(Model model)
    {
        ModelAndView view=new ModelAndView("homev");
        model.addAttribute("name","Jack");
        return view;
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing the wrong URL, need to include base url as well in your request.

```
http://localhost:8081/Spring_Practise/home/homev
```